Try to understand SSReflect's "have" and square bracket
I tried to understand square braket patterns I have seen in different proofs. So I followed the SSReflect example, and tried serveral patterns:
Lemma test : True.
Proof.
have : exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
Undo 1.
have []: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
Undo 1.
have [[]]: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
Undo 1.
have [[] []]: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
Undo 1.
have [a b]: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
Abort.

I understand there are two assumption in the term following have:

exists v : nat
v > 0

And the result by these cases are easy to understand:

have : exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
have []: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
have [a b]: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.

However, I don't understand these two:

have [[]]: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
After this line the screen becomes:

  ============================
  forall n : nat, 0 < n.+1 -> True

goal 2 (ID 53105) is:
 0 < 0 -> True

Actually I was suprised that I could break deeper. I guess it is because v: nat so after breaking the two assumption by the first [], it breaks deeper to the natural number and finds there are two constructors in the inductive type of nat, so there are two new assumptions for +1 and 0. But I don't understand how they are corresponding to

0 < n.+1
0 < 0

Especially that for the 0 < 0 it is an impossible case.

have [[] []]: exists v : nat, v > 0; last first.
After this line the screen becomes:


  ============================
  forall n : nat, 0 < n.+2 -> True

goal 2 (ID 53119) is:
 0 < 1 -> True
goal 3 (ID 53110) is:
 0 < 0 -> True


I thought it would be like have [a b] but I was wrong. For this one I totally don't know where they are from:

 forall n : nat, 0 < n.+2
0 < 1 -> True
0 < 0 -> True

Compare to have [a b], which is pretty straightforward to understand -- the two assumptions are named after the breaking.

  a : nat
  b : 0 < a
  ============================
  True



When I searched for answers, I tried to read the paper introduced SSReflect:
https://inria.hal.science/inria-00258384v16/document
But the section it explains square bracket is more about the specificaution, not when to use which pattern and what is the effect:
5.4 Introduction
I understand reading specification is good, but without examples it is difficult to understand what it is talking about. So I found that when I face a lemma I need to prove, or I need to read a proof, I usually got help from cheatsheets and tutorals -- they tell you for when to use them and what is the effect of using them. But I worry I may learn SSReflect in a wrong way. So it will be appreciated if there is any suggestion for learning SSReflect as well. Thanks.
